# Yii - How to get data from another model

Tags: php, mysql, sql-server, yii

Good morning

How do I get a data from another model.?
I have a search field where I need to search a project name. then my Cgridview will display the selected projects.

I have this in my relations

```
public function relations() {
        return array(
            'project' => array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'RmProjects', 'project_id'),
        );
    }
```

i tred to access project_name in the search function in my model..

```
public function search($employee, $search_date_start, $search_date_end, $search) {

        $criteria = new CDbCriteria;
        $criteria->with = array('eval' => array('together' => true));

        $criteria->compare('employee_id', $this->employee_id);
        $criteria->compare('remarks', $this->remarks, true);
        $criteria->compare('eval_id', $this->eval_id);

        //I tried it like this
        $criteria->addSearchCondition('project.project_name', $search);           

        if ($employee != '') {
            $criteria->compare('t.employee_id', $employee->company_id);
        }    
        return new CActiveDataProvider($this, array(
            'criteria' => $criteria,
        ));
    }
```

when I do this, I get an error.

> CDbCommand failed to execute the SQL statement: SQLSTATE[42S22]:
>   Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'project.project_name' in 'where
>   clause'. The SQL statement executed was: SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT
>   `t`.`id`) FROM `trx_evaluation_details` `t` LEFT OUTER JOIN
>   `trx_evaluation` `eval` ON (`t`.`eval_id`=`eval`.`id`) WHERE
>   ((project.project_name LIKE :ycp0)

what is wrong with my code.? I tried connecting the RmProject model in my current model so that I can access the project_name.. but instead, I get this error. Please help..

This is an edit:

This is my whole relations part

```
 public function relations() {
        return array(
            'eval' => array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'Evaluation', 'eval_id'),
            'project' => array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'RmProjects', 'project_id'),
        );
    }
```

I have added this in my model but it still did not work. it just changed the table.

```
$criteria->with = array('project' => array('together' => true));     
$criteria->addSearchCondition('project.project_name', $search);
```

this is my search function.

```
public function search($employee, $search_date_start, $search_date_end, $search) {            
        $criteria = new CDbCriteria;
        $criteria->with = array('eval' => array('together' => true));
        $criteria->with = array('project' => array('together' => true));                       

        $criteria->compare('employee_id', $this->employee_id);
        $criteria->compare('remarks', $this->remarks, true);
        $criteria->compare('eval_id', $this->eval_id);            

        $criteria->addSearchCondition('project.project_name', $search);
        $criteria->addSearchCondition('start_date', $search_date_start, 'AND');
        $criteria->addSearchCondition('end_date', $search_date_end, 'AND');

        if ($employee != '') {
            $criteria->compare('t.employee_id', $employee->company_id);
        }    

         if ($search_date_end !== '' && $search_date_start !== '' && $search !== '') {
                $criteria->condition = "start_date  >= '$search_date_start' AND end_date <= '$search_date_end' AND project.project_name like '%$search%'AND t.employee_id = '$employee->company_id'";                
            }

        return new CActiveDataProvider($this, array(
            'criteria' => $criteria,
        ));
    }
```

[image]

Comment: Error is quite clear. There is no project table in the sql generated. You need to use either  t.project_name or eval.project_name depending on which table contains the column - project_name.

Comment: project_name is in another model which is the RmProject that i tried in my relations.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't add model to your search method

```
$criteria->together = true;
$criteria->with = array('eval','project');
$criteria->addSearchCondition('project.project_name', $search);
```

Also it's not a good solution to set searching value via method's attributes. Define new model public attribute, define a rule and use it in search.

```
public $project_name;

public function attributeLabels(){
   return array(
       //... your other labels there
       'project_name' => 'Project Name',
   );
}

public function rules(){
   return array(
      //... your other rules there
      array('project_name', 'safe', 'on' => 'search'),
   );
}

public function search(){
   $criteria->compare('project.project_name', $this->project_name);
}
```

Comment: *$criteria->together = true;
$criteria->with = array('eval','project');
$criteria->addSearchCondition('project.project_name', $search);*

i tried doing this but this does not join another table, instead replaces the trx_evaluation with rm_projects which now returns the error that it does not recognizes the start_date and end_date because these data is from the trx_evaluation table.

Comment: Your question was about error with `project` relation, so I give you a solve for it. As I can see you also didn't specify 'eval' relation which you tring to use.

Comment: hi @SiZE thanks for your reply and for your patience in addressing my question. i have edited my post and added my code. as you can see, i have 2 relations that i needed. the **project** where **my project_name** is located and my **eval** where my **start_date** and **end_date** are located..

Comment: @litlitDM you make a mistake with assigning to `with` param twice. Look at my first code example once again.

Comment: Also don't forget to set aliases `eval` and `project`.

Comment: i tried to change it but now i have this error..**The relation "project" in active record class "EvaluationDetails" is specified with an invalid foreign key "project_id". There is no such column in the table "trx_evaluation_details".**

Comment: the thing is i am trying to connect 3 tables in here..
trx_evaluation_details ted.. 
trx_evaluation eval.. 
rm_projects. proj.. 

ted and eval are connected through eval_id.. 
eval and proj are connected through proj_id.. 

what im trying to do is connect ted and proj.. but they dont have any foreign key..

Comment: Show your table structure

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this issue.

in my relations(), i have added this line

```
'project' => array(self::HAS_ONE, 'RmProjects', array ('project_id'=>'project_id'), 'through'=> 'eval'),
```

this joins the models that has a connection that passes through another model. and then you can get the data from another model.. i hope that this answer can help anybody who has the same question as me.

you can read it in here.. which is in **relational query using through** http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/database.arr#relational-query-with-through