# Yii - Joining multiple tables

Tags: php, mysql, sql-server, join, yii

i am trying to join 3 tables in my model

```
trx_evaluation_details

trx_evaluation

rm_projects
```

`trx_evaluation_details` and `trx_evaluation` are already joined by using the relation function in my model.

```
'eval' => array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'Evaluation', 'eval_id'),
```

i am trying to join the `rm_projects` table so that i can access the `project_name` column in that table so i added this.

```
'project' => array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'RmProjects', 'project_id'),
```

so i have this relation in my model..

```
public function relations() {
        return array(                
            'eval' => array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'Evaluation', 'eval_id'),
            'project' => array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'RmProjects', 'project_id'),
        );
    }
```

i tried to access it like this..

```
if ($search_date_end !== '' && $search_date_start !== '' && $search !== '') {
                    $criteria->condition = "start_date  >= '$search_date_start' 
                    AND end_date <= '$search_date_end' 
                    AND project.project_name like '%$search%'
                    AND t.employee_id = '$employee->company_id'"; 
            }
```

where i tried project.project_name.. but it is returning an error

> CDbCommand failed to execute the SQL statement: SQLSTATE[42S22]:
>   Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'project.project_name' in 'where
>   clause'. The SQL statement executed was: SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT
>   `t`.`id`) FROM `trx_evaluation_details` `t` LEFT OUTER JOIN
>   `trx_evaluation` `eval` ON (`t`.`eval_id`=`eval`.`id`) WHERE
>   (start_date >= '2015-11-01' AND end_date <= '2015-12-01' AND
>   project.project_name like '%sprobe%'AND t.employee_id = '120069')

which means that it cannot see `project.project_name` and the table rm_projects is not joined in the returned error.

how can i access the project_name and how can i join the `rm_projects` table.?
please help.

Comment: I've answered you in previouse question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33949387/yii-how-to-get-data-from-another-model/33950665#33950665

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved this issue.

in my relations(), i have added this line

```
'project' => array(self::HAS_ONE, 'RmProjects', array ('project_id'=>'project_id'), 'through'=> 'eval'),
```

you can read it in here.. which is in **relational query using through** http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/database.arr#relational-query-with-through

this joins the models that has a connection that passes through another model. i hope that this answer can help anybody who has the same question as me.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried to solve your issue in the Model's search() method and made following changes. It works fine.

```
$criteria->with = array('eval', 'project');

if ($search_date_end !== '' && $search_date_start !== '' && $search !== '') {
        $criteria->condition = "start_date  >= '$search_date_start' 
        AND end_date <= '$search_date_end' 
        AND project.project_name like '%$search%'
        AND t.employee_id = '$employee->company_id'"; 
}
```

Please let me know, if you have any concern with this.

Thanks.

Comment: hi @AddWeb Solution Pvt Ltd.. unfortunately i tried your solution but it did not worked.. however i found something and i have solved this problem.. please see my answer..